# Program written in Visual C# or Visual C++ Requires .NET Framework

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is there a way to write a program either in Visual C# or Visual C++ such that the end-user won't need to have the .NET framework installed on their computers to run my program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use C++ and compile a native / win32 executable, not a managed / CLR targeted project.

Comment: yes. I do this regularly. Visual C++ is just a C/C++ compiler. Target computers may still need the MSVC runtime, though, depending on how you link your code.  But if you build in C#, then the target computer always needs the .NET Framework.

Comment: @Sev: No, there is no native C# compiler or native .NET framework alternative library supplied with Visual Studio.

Comment: Does this also mean that I choose Win32 Project when I start, and the  visual designing & drag-drop capabilities are removed?

Comment: @Sev: I'm not totally sure what you mean. You can use (e.g.) drag-and-drop created dialog box resources with native C++ executables.

Comment: @Charles: Well, I went to New -> Project and went down to Win32 instead of CLR and there is no form designer available.  Tho there is a form designer available under CLR->Windows Forms Designer.  So my question is, can I use Windows Forms Designer and still compile it to a native win32 executable?

Comment: @Sev: I suspect not. As I haven't ever had to create a CLR project I don't know what features you are used to and what the native equivalents, if any, are.

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ not a problem, C# will be really hard. In any event, I can't see why having .Net installed is such a problem, IIRC it is actually included in some windows distributions and service packs.

Comment: I just want to make it as portable as possible.  When you say really hard, do you mean impossible?  If not, what's the way to do it?

Comment: If your concern is portability you should use something like Qt.

Comment: @Sev What do you mean portable? If you compile an application using Win32 API calls it will only work on Microsoft Windows. I'm not counting WINE as a portable solution to Win32 binaries.

Comment: @Andrew I just meant portable in the sense of installations of Windows that don't have .NET Framework installed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply avoiding Microsoft, you can have them install [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

For Visual C# you could at least package your .NET app with the [.NET client profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc656912.aspx) (a subset of the full .NET Framework 4). This reduces the payload a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

While requiring a fair amount of manual effort, if you really must run without .NET installed, you can virtualize the runtime files in your app.

http://boxedapp.com/blog/2008/06/11/net-runtime-embedding/